# Git: Botched merging submodule into main module, pull won't overwrite files

Tags: git

I'm in a bit of a tight spot because I attempted to merge one of our submodules into the main repository.  I seem to have handled something slightly incorrectly, however, as when each user pulls on the target branch it refuses to merge because the files are still there from the old submodule.

This can be fixed with a :

```
rm -rf path/to/submodule
```

on the command line, but (A) I don't want to inconvenience people like this and (B) we have non-technical people doing testing that rely on a page which does a simple git pull to automatically retrieve changes.

How can I fix this?  Merges / pulls won't work on the target branch for people who have not manually removed the submodule until I can figure out a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional.  The enitre metadata of the the submodule including its history is stored in the submodule's `.git` folder.  If `git pull` would delete this information, it would be a highly destructive command.